# Facebook and Youtube apps dont play videos properly in Note 2

Tags: samsung, video

I use Samsung Note 2. it works fine. it has only one problem. video thumbnails in youtube and facebook app looks fine but when i play the  video pixels mix. touch screen , audio works fine. 
It is my first thread and i don't know  how to upload ss directly. so here is imgur version of problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnOQZ.jpg